# Define mapping array

Tags: c#, arrays, automapper

I have two classes:

```
public class Customer
{
    public string FirstName { get; set;  }

    public string LastName { get; set; }
};

public class Customer_
{
    public string FirstNam { get; set; }

    public string LastNam { get; set; }
}
```

And one instance of my class `Customer`:

```
Customer[] Customer = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName1",
        LastName = "LastName1"
    },
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName2",
        LastName = "LastName2"
    }
};
```

I want to map my object Customer to an instance of my object Customer_.

I use Automapper:

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.CreateMap<Customer, Customer_>();
});

IMapper mapper = config.CreateMapper();
var dest = mapper.Map<Customer[], Customer_[]>(Customer);
```

But the object `dest` is have two index null

How to create the map and and define mappings ? For example : Customer.FirstName = Customer_.FirstName ...etc

Edit :

I add a new property `Quantity` (type int) in my class Customer and a value in my instance. Now, I want to map only customer who have a quantity > x

```
Customer[] Customer = new Customer[]
{
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName1",
        LastName = "LastName1",
        Quantity = 11
    },
    new Customer()
    {
        FirstName = "FirstName2",
        LastName = "LastName2",
        Quantity = 5
    }
};
```

How do to ?

Comment: Why are the properties in the second type spelled differently?

Comment: For to test Automapper :)

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection) outlines this fairly clearly.

> Because the names of the destination properties do not exactly match the source property ..., we need to specify custom member mappings in our type map configuration:

```
cfg.CreateMap<Customer, Customer_>()
   .ForMember(dest => dest.FirstNam , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.FirstName))
   .ForMember(dest => dest.LastNam , opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.LastName))
```

Note that you have to explicitly map in the *other* direction if necessary as well.